# How to conditionally add closing and starting JSX tags

Tags: reactjs

I have never been able to figure out how to conditionally close off an existing JSX tag and start a new one without getting syntax errors in Visual Studio.  How is this done?  In the example below, I want to split an existing table into two tables.  I don't get any syntax errors if I remove the conditional code.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>

    {true ?
     </table> /* Close first table (Syntax error on this line because of no starting tag) */
     <table>  /* Create a new table by splitting the existing table */
    : null}

    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain more what data you're splitting into two tables? It might be more straightforward to do splitting/filtering before going into the rendering code.

Comment: @Ross Allen - I'm splitting the header into one table and the body into another table so I can have a fixed header.

Comment: I suggest splitting the data beforehand and preventing the need for conditionals in rendering. Can you include an example of the format of your data in your code sample?

Comment: @RossAllen - I would hate to have to split the tons of code that creates the table into two separate components.  One for Fixed Header and the other for dynamic header.  There has got to be a way to do conditional closing tags.

Comment: If you can provide an example of the code that generates the data for the Header and Body, it'd be easier to show how it's simpler to do conditional work before getting to JSX.

Comment: @RossAllen - The above code already shows the header (thead) and body sections of the table I am trying to split conditionally.  I copied this code from the "return" section of the jsx render.

Comment: Can you expand on the two `...` sections inside the head and body? What code goes in there that requires a conditional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `renderTable(rows)` method that I call for each group of rows that need to be in a separate table:

```
render() {
    let tables = [];
    let tableRows = [];

    this.props.rows.forEach(row => {
        tableRows.push(row);
        if (someCondition()) {
            // end the table after this row
            tables.push(this.renderTable(tableRows));
            tableRows = [];
        }
    });

    if (tableRows.length) {
        tables.push(this.renderTable(tableRows));
    }

    return <div>{tables}</div>;
}

renderTable(rows) {
    return <table>
        <tbody>
        {rows.map ..... }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should **not** close a HTML tag inside the curly braces `{}`, unless it is created inside the curly braces.

Examples:

```
<div>
{</div>} //wrong

<div>
  {1 + 5}
</div> //correct

<div>
  {2+3 === 5 ? <div>hello</div> : <div>world</div>}
</div> //correct

<div>
  {2+3 === 5 ? <div>{6 + 7}</div> : <div>{5 + 5}</div>}
</div> //correct
```

Adding to that, `{}` can contain only a single node of HTML tag. If you have multiple nodes of HTML inside `{}`, React will throw an error.

Examples

```
<div>
 {
  <span>{1+2}</span>
  <span>{1+2}</span>
 }
</div> //will throw an error

<div>
 {
  <span>
   <span>{1+2}</span>
   <span>{1+2}</span>
  </span> 
 } 
</div> //correct
```

Hope it help!!

**[Update]**

For your case

```
{
 true //if true, this table will be rendered, else, null will be returned
  ? <table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
 </table>
 : null
}
<table> //this table will render all the time
 <tbody>
     ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So how do I close the table in my example conditionally?

Comment: @Lambert Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a workaround for this problem, so I just manually solved the problem with an if statement.

```
if (condition === true) {
    return (<table>...</table> <table>...</table>);
} else {
    return (<table>...</table>);
}
```