# ReactJs - Add open and closing tag without syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to generate a form from a JSON with materialize.
Generate the form components is not a problem but Im not able to create `<span class="row">` to separate form inputs.

In my form component render method, Im iterating the json data and put every component (textfield, dropdown etc...) in an array and then return it.

```
render()
{
    return <span className="row"> { this.buildForm() } </span>
}
```

This works greats but every input are printed inside a single  row so I got problem when materialize has to manage input cols.

So I need to create dynamically the row span. 
In my json I put a specific attributes call "rowstart" and "rowend" for every input field so I know if that input will start a new row or will close one.

For example if I have two input with cols = 6, the first one will have rowstart=true and the second one will have rowend=false

The problem came in render. I cant put an open or a close tag in the render.

```
if (attributes.rowstart)
{
   formRender.push(<span className="row">);
}
switch(attributes['type'])
{
   case 'string': formRender.push(<TextField .... />); break;
   [...]
}
if (attributes.rowend)
{
    formRender.push(</span>);
}
```

The render doesn't allow open/close tag because its now sure what happens in the next iteration so it can't say if the open tag will be really close.

Is there a way to solve it?

Searching on StackOverlow i found this post but its different from what I need. [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774851/how-to-conditionally-add-closing-and-starting-jsx-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make rows a top level array elements and make every other inputs as children of rows

```

```
if (attributes.rowstart && attributes.children.length)
{
    let row = (<span className="row">{attributes.children.map((input)=> <Input key={input.name} /> )}</span>);
    formRender.push(row);
}
```

```

Comment: Your solution needs a json refactoring to put row information as a block and then put every input inside it. I will consider it.